# javascript/timing

Tags: javascript, html

I want to calculate the **time difference** between the **click** of **two buttons** using **java script**

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint - use:

```
var t = Date.now();
```

to get the current time (measured in milliseconds since 00:00:00 UTC on 01/01/1970) with millisecond *resolution*.

Note that the result will still be limited in *accuracy* by the system hardware.

On older browsers without `Date.now()`, use:

```
var t = new Date().valueOf();
```

or the terser

```
var t = +new Date();
```

The latter uses numeric coercion (the `+` prefix) to generate an automatic call to `.valueOf()`.

Comment: wuhaahh.. boy oh boy, that is a lot of typing! :D `+new Date()` or.. (better) `Date.now()` please

Comment: @jAndy I don't like using `+` for coercion, but the static method is handy - I didn't know about that one!

Comment: I would give it as optional since its part of the ES5 spec (even if its maybe the easiest method to shim). But if supported its even a few magnitudes faster than `new Date()` which is great for some higher performance measurements

Comment: @jAndy yes, definitely better not to create a `Date` object if you don't need to!

Answer (score 1):

- Get current time from the epoch in milliseconds: `new Date().getTime()`.
- Difference between times: `endTime - startTime`.
- Show message box: `alert("Message")`.

Guess these can be combined together as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider [performance.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance.now%28%29) for higher resolution timing.